# Azure function throws "Message processing error(Action=Complete)" after calling deadletterasync with autocomplete not setting as False

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Azure function throws "Message processing error(Action=Complete)" after calling deadletterasync with autocomplete not setting as False. But when I set "Autocomplete=false" even after processing successful messages it keeps retrying. What is the best way to receive message ,and deadletter when exception occurs?

```
public async Task Test(
        [ServiceBusTrigger(
            topicName: "testTopic",
            subscriptionName: "testSubsription",
            Connection = "testConnectionString",Autocomplete = false)]
        Message message,
        MessageReceiver messageReceiver,
        [ServiceBus("SendTopic", EntityType.Topic, Connection = "SendConnection")]
        IAsyncCollector<Message> output,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
        try
        { 

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestObject>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));
            foreach (var data in result.Data)
            {
               var convertedData= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
               var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(convertedData);
               Message outputMessages = new(byteArray);
               await output.AddAsync(outputMessages, cancellationToken);
               await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(lockToken);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          await messageReceiver.DeadLetterAsync(lockToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share your function code.

Comment: I have added the code used

Comment: Can you share the version of the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus package you're using?  The patterns in your code seem to imply that you're using a version earlier than 5.0, which uses the deprecated Service Bus SDK.   The answers below are assuming the current generation, requiring an extensions package in the 5.x line.

Comment: I am using version 4.3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you're using the message receiver to settle (dead-letter) the message. Instead, you should inject [`SerivceBusMessageActions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.servicebus.servicebusmessageactions?view=azure-dotnet) and use it to settle the message manually.

Comment: I am using version 4.3.0 . So, if I made autocomplete false on service bus trigger , can I make a call to completeAsync after the output.AddAsync () line? And I can use MessageReceiver.DeadLetterAsync() on exceptions.Will this be ok?

Comment: I don't remember off top of my head what 4.3.0 had. You'd have to inject into the method the receiver and use it to settle the message, not create a new receiver.

Comment: Yeah, I have updated the code above. Is this fine?

Comment: I wouldn't modify the original code for the question to give a chance others who read it ability to understand what was going on. But it looks right except completing the incoming message in a loop. And the locktoken coming from nowhere. You can validate it running locally with a service bus connection string to your testing namespace. Note that collector dispatches messages immediately IIRC. So if one of the multiple messages fails to be dispatched, you can't prevent previously send ones

Answer (score 0):

- I was able to  `deadletterqueue` a message when an exception occurs in azure function.

code :

```
// Servicebus Client
serviceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(conn);

// Creating Reciever
            ServiceBusReceiver reciever = client.CreateReceiver("test");

//Downloan message
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message = await reciever.ReceiveMessageAsync();

//try - catch block for Exception

            try {
                // Throwing the Exception
                throw new Exception();
            }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                // Deadlettering the message
               await reciever.DeadLetterMessageAsync(message);
                return new OkObjectResult("Exception");
            }

            string g = message.Body.ToString();

            return new OkObjectResult(g);
```

[image]

Comment: But you're not receiving the message using the function. Therefore it's not ASB triggered function. Something here is off. Unless it's a timer or HTTP function (something you've omitted in the code), this is not a good solution.